# Redirect all requests to root URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm terrible with .htaccess rules, so could you please help with this?

I'm look for this scenario:

```
No matter what subdomain the request is for, the visitor is 301'd to the root of the domain.
```

So, for example:

- http://www.doma.in is redirected to http://doma.in
- http://foo.doma.in is redirected to http://doma.in
- http://bar.doma.in is redirected to http://doma.in
- http://www.doma.in/images/image-1.png is redirected to http://doma.in/images/image-1.png
- http://foo.doma.in/images/image-2.png is redirected to http://doma.in/images/image-2.png
- http://bar.doma.in/images/image-3.png is redirected to http://doma.in/images/image-3.png

But also, just for `index.html`:

- http://www.doma.in/index.html is still redirected to http://doma.in
- http://foo.doma.in/index.html is still redirected to http://doma.in
- http://bar.doma.in/index.html is still redirected to http://doma.in

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RedirectMatch 301 (.*)doma.in(.*)$ http://doma.in$2` practically everything before "doma.in is ignored, but everything after the domain is redirected as normal (notice `$2`, `$1` is everything before the domain name "doma.in" but I think you don't need that ... if you do tell me and I will edit my answer)

hope it helped

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but would your answer also redirect `http://www.doma.in/index.html to http://doma.in/indexx.html`? I'd like it to redirect a request to `http://www.doma.in/index.html to http://doma.in`.

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 http://(.*)doma.in/index.html$ http://doma.in/indexx.html` `RedirectMatch 301 http://(.*)doma.in/index.html$ http://doma.in/` just noticed you want to make two different redirects for the same link (`/index.html`) I suggest you chose the one that fits your needs most

Comment: I've just clarified my question a little as I still don't think what you've suggested would work, as it would now only redirect the `index.tml` request :(

Comment: I apologize for not noticing that, in that case you can use `RedirectMatch 301 (.*/)index.html$ http://doma.in/`